# Socket programming - does client's input/output stream differ from server's input/output stream?

Tags: java, sockets, client-server, ipc, serversocket

When establishing a socket in order to achieve client/server communication socket is initialized at the client and at the server side. The way I understand this is that they have 1 FIFO bidirectional file. Now as far as I understood sockets, it means 1 input stream and 1 output stream of a single file, meaning if **client** is **writing** to its ***serverSocket.outputStream*** let's say, does it mean that **server** can't at the same time **write** to ***clientSocket.outputStream***. Is ***serverSocket.outputStream*** and ***clientSocket.outputStream*** the same FIFO file or is it constructing 2 FIFO files, 1 for client and 1 for server meaning that ***clientSocket.outputStream*** and ***clientSocket.inputStream*** refer to **different FIFO files**. It came to be confusing since both streams refer to the same socket within a program and than I intuitively think it needs to be the same file, meaning that there is **possibly** a **conflict** if ***clientSocket.outputStream*** **and** ***serverSocket.outputStream*** **write** to this file at the **same time**.
Could please someone help and clarify this? I wasn't able to understand it. Am I missing understanding of some underlaying important concept and if so which one?

Comment: None of this make any sense to me. There are *no* files involved at all, at least as far as the programmer is concerned. There is no difficulty at all with both the server and the client of a socket pair writing at the same time. In fact both the client and the server may both be reading and writing at the same time, so there are 2 read and 2 writes occurring simultaneously, providing the platform supports the appropriate concurrency features.